# Should I acknowledge an "automatic" holiday bonus?

Tags: employer-relations

I work for a small company in the US. Every December we get a holiday bonus. The bonus isn't mandatory and is not part of my negotiated salary. It's just a little extra we get at the end of the year which just shows up via direct deposit. **Am I supposed to acknowledge it in any way?** I never have in the past. I work remotely and am seldom in the main office but I'm wondering if I should send a thank you card, email, etc.

Comment: It is unclear how big the company is and whether or not you know the owner. If it is a big company with many levels of management then tank your manager. If it is a small company and the owner and you know each other, then thank the owner.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A thank you email to your direct manager and the manager above them is usually how I handled it.

Don't speak of the bonus to anyone else.  You don't know if others were included or not, or if they received different amounts.  Whether they did or didn't, whether it was the same, more, or less, nothing good will come from "comparing notes."

Say thank you, privately, and go on with your work.

Comment: "*Don't speak of the bonus to anyone else. You don't know if others were included or not, or if they received different amounts.*" -- excellent..

Comment: You can, of course, discuss your compensation all you want. In fact, in America, it's protected by the NLRB. You can't be disciplined for it, and you are able to talk about YOUR salary all you want. You can totally get fired for asking other people what they make, of course. Your boss certainly won't like it, and it will cause drama, but if you don't care to avoid that, then you're just playing your bosses' game of maintaining an information discrepancy and deflating wages for them.

Comment: I have no plans on discussing salaries/bonuses with anyone. I just wanted to know if I should send a (private) thank you to my boss.

Comment: @Adonalsium - I think that advice was not "you'll get in trouble if you do" as much as "why generate drama and/or resentment by causing a co-worker to suddenly feel slighted and unappreciated when you don't have to."

Comment: @Adonalsium - I was recommending that for the point of behaving with class, not for the point of avoiding your "Class Warfare" nonsense.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - from the tone of your post, I didn't believe that you would.  However, these answers are as much for the benefit of those that follow these questions later as they are for you, personally.

Comment: @WesleyLong You believe it is not appropriate to discuss wages with co-workers because all bosses want to squash such talk.

Comment: @Adonalsium - I believe that taking a bonus and turning it into some sort of confrontation leaves you a couple letters short of class.

Comment: Because you are taken in by first world working culture which sculpted by the employer class for their own means and goals.

Comment: @Adonalsium  -  No, because I am engaged in voluntary employment with an organization who has met every agreement I made with them with regards to amounts and schedules of compensation.

Comment: Employment is voluntary? What a laugh. I'll go live in the woods then, perhaps survive to the ripe age of 40 before I die of exposure, injury, or illness. It's my choice, after all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70695/discussion-between-wesley-long-and-adonalsium).

Comment: @WesleyLong how are you supposed to grasp the salary/bonus policy in your company if you do not discuss it with your trustworthy colleagues? It may be too late when you finally realize you are being underpaid.

Comment: @AdamSmith - Did the company pay you what was agreed when you were hired?  Then you're not underpaid.  This desire for "parity" is misplaced.  You know what you're worth.  You know what they offered.  You either accept it or you don't.  Whatever happened with everyone else is immaterial.

Comment: @WesleyLong  Starting salary is just one data point in your whole career at the company. The progression of your salary and associated bonuses are as important and without an idea of the company policy on them, it is going to be impossible to evaluate them.  Of course the desire of parity is legitimate. Would you say that a woman that wants to have a matching salary to her masculine counterpart is misplaced?

Answer (score -2):

Since it's a small company, and all of you know each other, besides it's a holiday bonus, I would simply suggest making a small present for everyone, or only your employers. Write a personal greeting in a postcard with a new year wish, anything that shows honesty and warm feelings. 
A bonus is a nice gesture from the employer so a symbolic gift from your side is very kind gesture too.

Comment: Gifts flow down, not up, unless by "small present" you're simply referring to a thank-you card with a personal message which is indeed perfectly appropriate. Your answer is a bit unclear and could do with being fleshed out. If you can take the time to reply you can take the time to write out "something" in full.